# Excel Web App error everyday after recreation

Tags: error, excel-services, office-web-apps

I try to View/Edit Excel documents (xlsx) in Office Web App SP1. I immediately get an error. "An unexpected error has occurred.". Word and Powerpoint both work fine. I have recreated the Excel Service Application with success, but it shows the same exact error and ULS logs the next day...

This is in my ULS Logs:

Process: w3wp.exe 
Level: Unexpected

> System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow
>   partially trusted callers.     at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Assembly
>   asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle
>   rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)      at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   fillCache)      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)      at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)      at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHost.TryCreateHostExtension(String
>   className, IHostExtension& extension)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.MossHost.MossHost.LoadHostExtensions()

Just a couple notes:
Excel Services is running.
Office Web Apps feature is enabled on the site collection.
Word and Powerpoint work fine.

Comment: I did a Office Web App repair that fixed it, but i'll see if that sticks tomorrow.

Comment: Error reoccurred this morning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to Uninstall Office Web Apps completely. Beware! It will disconnect you from the farm so keep your farm passphrase handy. I will reinstall Office Web Apps at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer to you a potential workaround. Maybe it's not best practice but may be acceptable in your environment. You can set trust mode in web application config to Full:

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```

It hepled me in similar situation (the same "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers" exception) once. It's turn off some code access security restrictions. At least it may hepls you until you'll find the real problem.

Comment: It's not worth it. It's only Excel web application. Everything else works great.

Comment: So you can configure this option in Excel web application, can't you?

Comment: I want to stay in good practice anyways. There has to be another way.

Comment: Whats the current build level for SharePoint? If you can go to a hotfix it might be worth it. August 2011 CU has been well tested.

Comment: My build is 14.0.6029.1000 on SharePoint Server and Office Web Apps.

Comment: My build is October 2011 on SharePoint Server and Office Web Apps SP1 (only update).